# Android new Locale("en_US") and Locale.US are different?

Tags: android

I just ran into this problem when testing the locale set in the preferences against constant values:

```
(new Locale("en_US")).equals(Locale.US) == false
```

When looking at the details it turns out that new `Locale("en_us")` returns an object with a language code "en_us" and a country code that is a zero length string whereas `Locale.US` returns an object with language code "en" and country code "US". `Locale("en","US")` returns the same result as Locale.US so its easy to avoid this problem, but is this the expected behavior of the Locale constructors?

Comment: That's the wrong constructor. a Single parameter defines the language, en_US compared to US as expected. Use Locale(String language, String country) as you already stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locale constructors are working as expected. You can compare the locale objects like this:

> (new Locale("en_US")).toString().equalsIgnoreCase((Locale.US).toString())

It will give you the expected value

Comment: getDefault() returns a dynamic value, i would avoid this since it will definetely throw exceptions on devices with a different locale

Comment: @M.Bennett: Thanks, improved my answer

Comment: Thanks. This probably also explains why new Locale("en_US") will create a Locale that "sometimes" works, for example with functions that test for a certain locale this way.